# Здравствуйте, нужно чтобы выглядело как на скриншоте снизу. (проблема с иконками и с исчезновением блоков)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, frontend

```js
$(function(){
 $('.faq__quest').click(function(e) {
  $('.faq__quest').not(this).next().removeClass('show').slideUp(550);
  $(this).next().toggleClass('show').slideToggle(550, function(){
   $('.faq__quest').toggleClass("bgi");
  });
  
});


});
```

```css
.faq__questions {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.faq__question {
 width: 50%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 30px;
 
}
.faq__quest {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding-right: 105px;
 padding-left: 30px; 
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 90px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px rgba(238, 77, 71, 0.1);
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.faq__answer{
 display: flex;
 padding: 40px 0 0;
 padding-right: 105px;
 padding-left: 30px; 
 background-color: #FFF7F5;
 height: 120px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 border-top-right-radius: none;
 border-top-left-radius: none;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin-top: -10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 
}
.faq__quest.bgi::after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32339.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 right: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 transition: all .2s;
}
.faq__quest::after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-image: url(https://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG55.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 right: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 transition: all .2s;
}
.faq__answer {
 display: none;
}
.faq-load__btn{
 text-align: right;
}
.faq-load__btn button{
 border: none;
 width: 565px;
 height: 90px;
 background-color: rgba(237, 77, 71, 0.2);
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-top: 23px;
 position: relative;
 color: #ED4D47;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 outline: none;

}
.faq-load__btn button::after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-image: url(../images/plus.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 right: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq__questions">
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">What is a professional traffic permit?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">When is a professional traffic permit needed?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">How much does a commercial traffic permit cost for goods?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">Where to look for a traffic permit?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">Are there professional traffic permit training courses at a distance?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">Are there differences between a traffic permit and a professional traffic permit?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">How to check the traffic condition?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">How much does a commercial traffic permit cost for goods?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">What are the requirements for a professional traffic permit?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">How to plug in for the traffic permit test?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">Are there professional traffic permit training courses at a distance?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="faq__question">
      <div class="faq__quest bgi">How is the sample for a professional traffic permit booked?</div>
      <div class="faq__answer">Traffic permits are a requirement for conducting professional traffic.</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="faq-load__btn">
    <button>Load more</button>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/grsssh/459swj1d/7/ ссылка на jsfiddle

должно получится как на скриншоте: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjsPw.png

Не знаю, как сделать чтобы при клике на конкретный вопрос менялся плюс на минус только у него, а не у всех вопросов. А также чтобы, когда вопрос открывался надо чтобы другие вопросы под ним исчезали(как на скриншоте).

Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понятна реализация, вы задаете всем элементам, картинку минус в .faq__quest::after, потом картинку плюс .faq__quest.bgi::after. Потом при каждом клике вы меняте у всех элементов класс bhi, $('.faq__quest').toggleClass("bgi"); что собственно и переключает всем минус и плюс

Comment: По "исчезанию" вам наверное нужно сделать общий блок фиксированый по высоте и добавить overflow:hidden тогда при открытии, элементы которые не помещаются будут прятаться, так нужно?

Comment: @ ArturasLapinskas, с иконками поняла, спасибо. А про исчезновение, надо чтобы не полностью общий блок скрывался, а только элементы которые расположены под конкретным вопросом. Допустим если открываешь первый вопрос, то исчезает второй и третий вопросы в столбце. И также не должен отъезжать соседний столбец, когда открываешь вопрос в другом столбце. При этом высота общего блока не меняется и количество вопросов остается таким же(за исключением скрытых).

Comment: С исчезанем это самый простой вариант, посложнее можно сделать функцию которая будет высчитывать оставшуюся высоту и скрывать или показывать нужные блоки, каждый раз при открытии/закрытии

Comment: Так а как примерно нужно сделать хотя бы чтобы блоки исчезали?

Comment: По тому же принципу, что меняете плюс на минус - добавляете блоку класс, например .hidden и в css ему ставите display:none, или visibility:hidden, или height:0

Comment: @ArturasLapinskas спасибо))